# Error 404 on the side because of <?php echo wc_get_cart_url; ?>

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am getting an error 404 because of Cart element.

Here is the script (it can be found at the header.php under the theme folder):

```
<ul class="mobile-topnav container"><li>
<div class="mini-cart">
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url; ?>" class="cart-contents" title="<?php _e('View Cart', 'trav') ?>">
<i class="soap-icon-shopping"></i>
<div class="item-count">cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Search engine getting error 404 ..
of houndred of pages .

example reported dead link :

https://example.com/..?php%20echo%20wc_get_cart_url;%20?>
https://example.com/privacy-policy/..?php%20echo%20wc_get_cart_url;%20?>
..... ( there is more then 200 pages like that )

(I have no idea why its add the code at the end of the links) but I need to fix it fast because of googlebot scanning issue .

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code on this line:

```
<div class="item-count">cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
```

It should be:

```
<div class="item-count"><?php echo cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
```

Comment: Thank for your very fast reply! 

i made the change , but i`m still getting the same error .
( i scan my site using brokenlinkcheck )

Comment: <ul class="mobile-topnav container"><li>
<div class="mini-cart">
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url; ?>" class="cart-contents" title="<?php _e('View Cart', 'trav') ?>">
<i class="soap-icon-shopping"></i>
<div class="item-count">get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
</a>
</div>

Comment: Hi, the new code example you've sent has the same error.  You're trying to run the function get_cart_contents_count() but it needs to be within PHP tags.  E.g. <?php get_cart_contents_count() ?>

I also think you need will need to echo the returned value of get_cart_contents_count(), so add "echo" before it, e.g. <?php echo cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart-contents" title="<?php _e('View Cart', 'trav'); ?>">
<i class="soap-icon-shopping"></i>
<div class="item-count">/<?php cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
</a>
```

Your code is missing open tags, semicolons and the brackets for function calls.